# How to fix my plot in following graph in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to achieve a graph that looks like this:
[image: Graph I made in Excel]

I did that in Microsoft Excel but now I was trying to achieve the same results in Jupyter Notebook but I am stuck please guide me in correct direction:
This is what I have tried:

```
x_coordinates = [1000, 10000, 100000,250000,500000,1000000]

y1_coordinates = [0.016, 0.096, 0.9893,2.9166,9.2952,21.779]
y2_coordinates = [0.13, 15.215, 557.45,4768.842,55577.73,77777]
plt.xlabel('number of elements(n)') 
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y1_coordinates)

plt.ylabel('time in secs') 
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y2_coordinates)
```

But it does not give me exact results it looks like this so far:

[image: My result so far]

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the x-axis spacing.  The spacings in your Excel graph are not proportional to the differences between numbers; it's not linear or logarithmic.  So you can just plot the y-values against integers, and then rename the `ticks` after.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540730/how-to-make-xticks-evenly-spaced-despite-their-value):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))

x_coordinates = [1000, 10000, 100000,250000,500000,1000000]
x_positions = range(len(x_coordinates)) # get int positions

y1_coordinates = [0.016, 0.096, 0.9893,2.9166,9.2952,21.779]
y2_coordinates = [0.13, 15.215, 557.45,4768.842,55577.73,77777]

# plot against integers
plt.xlabel('number of elements(n)')
plt.plot(x_positions, y1_coordinates)

plt.ylabel('time in secs')
plt.plot(x_positions, y2_coordinates)

# relable with coordinates
plt.xticks(ticks=x_positions, labels=x_coordinates)
```

[image]

The orange curve still looks different at x=500000 though; but that seems like it is just slightly different data being plotted.

You could also achieve a similar by just converting the `x_coordinates` to strings:

```
# this makes the same graph as above
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(7,2)) # for size

x_coordinates = [1000, 10000, 100000,250000,500000,1000000]
x_coordinates = [str(i) for i in x_coordinates]

y1_coordinates = [0.016, 0.096, 0.9893,2.9166,9.2952,21.779]
y2_coordinates = [0.13, 15.215, 557.45,4768.842,55577.73,77777]

# plot against integers
plt.xlabel('number of elements(n)')
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y1_coordinates)

plt.ylabel('time in secs')
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y2_coordinates)
```

The thing with the table under the x-axis is more unique; I'm not sure of an easy way to easily to that in `matplotlib`.  If that's more the part you are interested in, you can maybe edit your question/create a new issue (but [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211064/aligning-table-to-x-axis-using-matplotlib-python) or [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/table_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-table-demo-py)).

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this with below code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x_coordinates = [1000, 10000, 100000,250000,500000,1000000]
y1_coordinates = [0.016, 0.096, 0.9893,2.9166,9.2952,21.779]
y2_coordinates = [0.13, 15.215, 557.45,4768.842,55577.73,77777]
fig.suptitle('Insertion Sort v/s Merge Sort', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('number of elements(n)') 
plt.ylabel('time in secs') 
plt.xscale('symlog')
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y1_coordinates,'b',lw=2)
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y2_coordinates,'orange',lw=2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.f")) # major axis formattter
plt.grid()
```

[image: OutputImage]

For the table, I would suggest to follow @Tom 's suggestion.